# Weird sketch size/memory/compiler (?) related issue (hanging, RX led on)

Tags: arduino-leonardo, arduino-pro-micro

Also posted at: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=549672.0

is there anyone who experienced similar problem or knows a solution to it?

The problem is that after uploading the code Arduino Pro Micro hangs (and RX led is constantly on).

The problem occurs instantly after turning on the microcontroller even if I put "delay(10000);" at the begining of the code trying to see at which point the error occurs.

The problem can be "fixed" by adding '**Serial.print("aa");**' at random place within the code...
Which results in the following output during upload:

```
Sketch uses 18318 bytes (63%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
Global variables use 1814 bytes (70%) of dynamic memory, leaving 746 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2560 bytes.
```

Suprisingly, using '**Serial.print("a");**" instead does not fix the problem. It results in the following output during upload:

```
Sketch uses 18314 bytes (63%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
Global variables use 1810 bytes (70%) of dynamic memory, leaving 750 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2560 bytes.
```

It seems very weird to me that adding serial print instruction with certain length (at seemingly random place) can solve such problem...

Another circumstance which seems to be solving the problem is commenting out one of the 2 lines (does not matter which):

```
sprintf(at_cmd, "AT+NAME%s\0", bluetoothName);
sprintf(at_pin_cmd, "AT+PIN%s\0", pin);
```

It's a spaghetti code so I doubt anyone will analyse it but just in case if anyone wanted to check it for some more or less obvious characteristic (e.g. F()/eeprom/memory extensive use or something...) then here it is: [Hastebin - link](https://hastebin.com/oyarezebiv.cpp)

I'm using "Arduino Pro Micro 5V" and Arduino IDE 1.8.5 with "Arduino Leonardo" board setting

Comment: You should make more use of PROGMEM for your string constants.  Use the _P variants of the string library functions.

Comment: You may want to look up how to use `PROGMEM`, That will let you move your arrays and global string literals to program space instead of taking up RAM

Comment: Does the only occur after uploading a new sketch or also after pressing the reset button or power-cycling?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but what do you guys think about the potential cause of the problem which I described?

Comment: @Gerben It happens after unplugging and plugging it back too. Not only after uploading.

Comment: Most strange hangings are caused by lack of RAM or buffer overruns. Using PROGMEM will help if it's the former that is the cause. It may also help you find where a buffer overrun is while you refactor your code.

Comment: Also asked here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=549672.0

Comment: Your description of the fault that goes away with some random print statement placed anywhere smacks of a buffer overrun somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Delta_G Wouldn't the code at least run until that overrun moment in such case? That's why I tested "delay(10000)" at the begining of setup function and realized it was not executed at all.

Comment: No.  An overrun causes undefined behavior.  That means it could fail at boot or when it gets to a certain line or it could make little demons fly out from your nose.   Anything goes with undefined behavior.